# Decorating a method of an instance with a method from another instance

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-class

I'm fairly new to Python.
I have 2 classes and for each class I have an instance.
I want to decorate a method of one of the instances with a method from the other instance, ie something like :

```
import functools

class DecoClass():
    def __init__(self, deco_arg):
        self.deco_arg = deco_arg

    def my_decorator(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def deco_wrapper(*args):
            print ('deco_wrapper argument :', self.deco_arg) # or just do something with deco_arg
            f = f(*args)
            return f
        return deco_wrapper

###

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, arg, decorator):
            self.arg = arg
            self.decorator = decorator

    @self.decorator.my_decorator            # this is my problem, how can I do this ?
    def my_function(self):
        print ('my_function : ', self.arg)

###

if __name__ == "__main__":
a = DecoClass(1)
b = MyClass(10, a)
b.my_function()
```

The above doesn't work of course because `MyClass` has no knowledge of `self.decorator` attribute (at the class level). Can this be done or is there another way ?

PS. The above example is an oversimplification. In my case, `DecoClass()` will actually be responsible for exception catching, error logging (to file and/or mysql) and various other things. I simply want to instantiate it once so that I won't have to pass arguments (logger, db auth etc) each time I want to use it. Also, `DecoClass()` will reside in a module that will be used by different python programs at the same time (each instance will have its own arguments).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can't do that this way unless you use a class variable, not an instance variable. In which case, you should probably ust decorate it directly.

Answer (score 0):

This may not meet your needs, but you can try this:

```py
import functools

class DecoClass():
    def __init__(self, deco_arg):
        self.deco_arg = deco_arg

    def my_decorator(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def deco_wrapper(*args):
            print ('deco_wrapper argument :', self.deco_arg)
            r = f(*args)
            return r
        return deco_wrapper

###

a = DecoClass(1)
decorator = a.my_decorator

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, arg):
            self.arg = arg
            self.decorator = decorator

    @decorator
    def my_function(self):
        print ('my_function : ', self.arg)

###

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = MyClass(10)
    b.my_function()
```